# How to replace Unicode characters with ASCII in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this text: `"QWERTY\\\\u0119"`
How can I convert this text into normal text without unicode?

I've tried many ways, but nothing in the result. For example I've tried this one:

```
myString.cString(using: .utf8)
```

or I've created an extension for String:

```
func utf8DecodedString()-> String {
    let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
    if let message = String(data: data!, encoding: .nonLossyASCII){
        return message
    }
    return ""
}
```

but they are not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the desired output when `"QWERTY\\\\u0119"` is the input?

Comment: @Carpsen90 it's "QWERTYę"

Comment: Unicodes are written with brackets "QWERTY\u{0119}". have a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: @Carpsen90 thanks! But why my string does not have brackets and how can I add them?

Comment: How do you get that string?

Comment: The title of your question is wrong. If you want to convert `"QWERTY\\\\u0119"` to `"QWERTYę"` then a better title would be something like "How to replace character escape codes with Unicode characters".